# Split localized iOS app into separate apps

Tags: ios, localization

I have a dual language localized app that is intended for enterprise distribution and for my purposes, it would be desirable to split it into two separate apps. Some users of the app would need to use both language versions and it would be easier for them to just open a different app than to go into settings and change language each time they want to switch.

What is the easiest way to split such an app into two targets, considering it already has a couple of localized *strings* files (for text and for InfoPlist) and several language-specific image folders?

Comment: It is possible to let the users switch between languages from within the app, I mean there are ways to switch language from code instead of relying on the iOS language setting. So you could add a "language-switch" button in top right corner or something. Although this is not default app behaviour, Apple won't reject this because there are apps in the appstore that do just that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new target (one project might have more than 1 target), with a different bundle identifier.

Add a preprocessor macro, e.g. SECONDARY_LANGUAGE=1, into the new target's **Build Settings** so you'll know which language is being used. You can check for language inside the code with something like

```
#if (SECONDARY_LANGUAGE)
    ...
#else
    ...
#endif
```

Comment: Yes, that's the typical way I split apps that have minor differences and major similarities in functionality or content. I was hoping for something smarter that takes advantage of the existing language.lproj directories, but all localization settings seem to be per project instead of per target at this point.